# How to multiple data retrieve from Servlet to JSP text field separately using Ajax?

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I,m newer for ajax. I want to learn that how to retrieve data from servlet to JSP page. When search by ID or name from jsp i want get related data to that id and load them to servlet. then send to jsp file and display them in separate text field. I have develop jsp file and servlet file separately. give me a support to understand ajax data send and retrieve method simply..

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Comment: Hmm, servlet and JSP page are both on the server side. Ajax is a call (http-request)  from the client side (browser) to the server.

Comment: can you give an example code to understand the process.